# How to implement bind() for Lua?

Tags: lua

I want to implement `bind()` for Lua, which is widely used in Javascript to create closures.

Below code demos 1 argument case:

```
function bind(func, arg1)
  return function (...)
    return func(arg1, ...)
  end
end

local x = { data = 1 }
function x.print(self)
  print self.data
end

outputX = bind(x.print, x)
outputX() -- print 1
```

My question is: how to support any number of binding arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [lua-vararg](https://github.com/moteus/lua-vararg) you can write:

```
local va = require "vararg"

function bind(f, ...)
  local outer_args = va(...)
  local function closure (...)
    return f(va.concat(outer_args, va(...)));
  end
  return closure;
end

bind(print, 1, 2, 3)(4,5,6)
```

this is pure lua implementation

```
function packn(...)
  return {n = select('#', ...), ...}
end

function unpackn(t)
  return (table.unpack or unpack)(t, 1, t.n)
end

function mergen(...)
  local res = {n=0}
  for i = 1, select('#', ...) do
    local t = select(i, ...)
    for j = 1, t.n do
      res.n = res.n + 1
      res[res.n] = t[j]
    end
  end
  return res
end

function bind(func, ...)
  local args = packn(...)
  return function (...)
    return func(unpackn(mergen(args, packn(...))))
  end
end

bind(print, 1, nil, 2, nil)(3, nil, 4, nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way Lua handles `...` and multiple return values, the obvious way doesn't work:

```
function bind(func, ...)
  local args = {...}
  return function (...)
    return func(unpack(args), ...)
  end
end
```

That fails because the multiple return values from `unpack` will be [adjusted down to 1 return value, due to the way it's used in the expression](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5).

You can do this, which will work in a limited fashion:

```
function bind(func, ...)
  local nargs = select("#", ...)
  local args = {...}
  return function (...)
    local newArgs = {...}
    local fullArgs = {}
    copy(fullArgs, args)
    copy(fullArgs, {...})
    return func(unpack(fullArgs))
  end
end
```

The `copy` function above is just a simple utility function that copies the array elements from one table to another.

The limitation here is that none of the arguments, to either the `bind` call nor the functor, are allowed to be `nil`. If they are, those arguments and any after them will be culled.

Doing this correctly would be quite easy using the C API. But due to the restrictions of the Lua language, it's exceedingly difficult to pull off with proper `nil` handling.

Comment: to suppurt nil your `copy` function should retrieve 2 additional parameters. `position` and `count`. `copy(fullArgs,args,1,nargs);copy(fullArgs,{...},nargs+1,select('#',...));`

Comment: No you can `unpack(fullArgs, 1, nargs + select('#', ...))`

Answer (score 1):

define an `unpackN` function that unpacks a table of arguments:

```
function unpackN(argss, i)
    i = i or 1

    local iLocal = i
    for _, args in ipairs(argss) do
        local argsN = #args

        if iLocal <= argsN then
            return args[iLocal], unpackN(argss, i+1)
        end

        iLocal = iLocal-argsN
    end
end
```

and use it as follows:

```
function bind(func, ...)
    local A = {...}
    return function (...)
        local B = {...}
        return func(unpackN {A, B} )
    end
end
```

Comment: Your code does not work with nil. Try test `bind(print, 1, nil, 2, nil)(3, nil, 4, nil)`

Comment: `#{1, 2, nil, 3} == 4`, `#{1, 2, nil, 3, nil} == 2`. A little confusing.. OK, I learned that never put a nil in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function bind(func, ...)
    local rest = {...}

    return function (...)
        local args = {}

        for i = 1, #rest do
            args[i] = rest[i]
        end

        for i = 1, select("#", ...) do
            table.insert(args, select(i, ...))
        end

        return func(unpack(args))
    end
end
```

Now you have a variadic bind:

```
function add(...)
    local sum = 0

    for i = 1, select("#", ...) do
        sum = sum + select(i, ...)
    end

    return sum
end

local add_2_3 = bind(add, 2, 3)

print(add_2_3(5))
```

Hope that helps.